# Help to translate "No matter how difficult and hard something is, I will always be positive and smile like an idiot."

Tags: translation

Someone can help me to translate this in Korean please?

"No matter how difficult and hard something is, I will always be positive and smile like an idiot."

Comment: Hi Anne-Abel - do you have a bit more context as to why you need the translation (in case that changes the best way to translate it)?

Comment: Google translation is good :

아무리 어렵고 힘든 일이라도 나는 언제나 긍정적 인 태도와 바보처럼 웃을 것입니다.

Answer (score 1):

Google translation is good :

아무리 어렵고 힘든 일이라도 나는 언제나 바보처럼 긍정적이고 웃을 것입니다.

No matter how difficult and hard something is (그것이) 아무리 어렵고 힘든 것임에도 불구하고

I will always be 나는 언제나 ~ 일 것이다

positive and smile like an idiot 바보처럼 긍정적이고 웃는

Comment: I'd say 긍정적으로 rather than 긍정적이고.